# Раздельная сборка связанных модулей ядра Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

Требуется собрать два модуля `a` и `b` отдельно друг от друга, при этом один связан с другим.
Поясню на примере:
`файл a.c`

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Vasya Pupkin <vasya@pupkin.ru>");

void hello_print_msg(void)
{
    printk( KERN_ALERT "CALL: hello_print_msg()\n" );
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(hello_print_msg);

int __init hello_init(void)
{
  printk( KERN_ALERT "Hello, world!\n" );
  return 0;
}

void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
  printk ( KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world!\n" );
}
```

`файл a.c`

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Vasya Pupkin <vasya@pupkin.ru>");

extern void hello_print_msg(void);

int __init hello_init(void)
{
  printk( KERN_ALERT "Hello, world!\n" );
  hello_print_msg();
  return 0;
}

void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
  printk ( KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world!\n" );
}
```

Имеем общий `Makefile`

```
CURRENT := $(shell uname -r)
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m := hello_a.o hello_b.o
hello_a-objs := a.o
hello_b-objs := b.o

all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

На данном этапе модули собираются и загружаются в последовательности: `a` -> `b`, т.к. `b` вызывает функцию из `a`.

---

Изменим условия задачи, разнесём модули по разным папкам, и для каждого создадим свой Makefile.
Теперь при сборке модуля `b` видим предупреждение `WARNING: "hello_print_msg" [...../b/hello_b.ko] undefined!`
Если же теперь из папки с модулем `a` скопировать (заменив) файл `Module.symvers` в папку с модулем `b`, и опять выполнить команду `make`, всё замечательно соберётся!

---

Вопрос: Существует ли другой способ сообщить сборщику модулей ядра Linux где искать файлы со списками экспортируемых символов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

это описано в [документации](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt), в секции *6.3 Symbols From Another External Module*.

ниже — мой вольный перевод:

## 6.3. идентификаторы из другого внешнего модуля

иногда один внешний модуль использует идентификаторы из другого внешнего модуля. `kbuild` должен знать о них, чтобы не надоедать предупреждениями о неизвестных идентификаторах. существует три решения.

*примечание*: первый метод — рекомендуемый, но он может и не подойти.

### использование `kbuild`-файла в каталоге выше уровнем

если у вас два модуля, `foo.ko` и `bar.ko`, и модулю `foo.ko` требуются идентификаторы из `bar.ko`, вы можете использовать общий `kbuild`-файл из каталога уровнем выше — оба модуля будут скомпилированы в процессе одной сборки. рассмотрим следующую структуру каталогов:

```
./foo/ - содержит foo.ko
./bar/ - содержит bar.ko
```

тогда `kbuild`-файл может выглядеть, например, так:

```
#./Kbuild (или ./Makefile)
obj-y := foo/ bar/
```

и выполнение

```
$ make -C $KDIR M=$PWD
```

приведёт к сборке обоих модулей с полной информацией обо всех идентификаторах.

### использование дополнительного файла `Module.symvers`

при сборке внешнего модуля генерируется файл `Module.symvers`, содержащий все экспортируемые идентификаторы, не определённые в ядре. для получения доступа к идентификаторам из `bar.ko` скопируйте файл `Module.symvers` из каталога сборки этого модуля в каталог, где будет собираться `foo.ko`. в процессе сборки `kbuild` прочитает этот файл и по окончании будет создан новый `Module.symvers`, содержащий «сумму» описанных идентификаторов, не являющихся частью ядра.

### использование переменной `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS`

если копирование файла `Module.symvers` не подходит, можно присвоить разделённый пробелами список файлов переменной `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` в `kbuild`-файле. эти файлы будут загружены `modpost`-ом во время инициализации таблиц идентификаторов. пример:

```
#./foo/Kbuild (или ./foo/Makefile)
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := $(TOPDIR)/path/to/bar/Module.symvers
```

Comment: Замечательно! третий вариант то что нужно. Но один момент всплыл, KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS с относительным путём не сработал, только с абсолютным. Видимо это связано с тем текущим каталогом при сборке является каталог с исходниками ядра.

Comment: @dsnk, да, действительно, добавленный мною пример — неправильный. заменил путь на абсолютный. спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Дочитав до п.4.3 (раньше не понимал важности этого документа) нашёл на мой взгляд универсальное решение `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := $(abspath $(if $(src),$(src)/)../a/Module.symvers)`